# Password change in external identity providers

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am using azure ad login provider in IdentityServer, Now when the user password in azure changes, I want to block all subsequent token requests from client. Is there any possibility??

Comment: Wouldn't it just behave like that anyway if you use azure ad as login provider? If a user changes password, new calls to `connect/authorize` will prompt for new password?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius, Login screen will be at IdentityServer and once click login using Azure, id_token will be passed back to IDS and now IDS will give us access_token and id_token. So the next all connect/authorize requests to IDS will be valid , coz i am changing the password in Azure not at IDS.